# Reassign a Variable

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want so save the name of my last vertex.
Finally I realized `\def` doesn't make reassignments. So I always use the coordinates of the first vertex "14". But it sould be "14" "13" "12". 
Furthermore the three lowest horizontal lines should have the same length like the second lowest line of the successor node.
What you can also see is, that I don't know how to link (and/or/||/&&) expressions in an if statement and don't know how to express a negation (!). Is LaTeX even able to do that without 20 additional packages and confusing and inconsistent new syntax??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{amsmath,amstext,pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!20,minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt]

    \foreach \e/\l/\name in {0/2/11, 3.5/5.5/12, 8.6/10.6/13, 14/16.5/14}
    {
        \coordinate (PPE-\name) at (\l,-1.0); %save position for maxPushforward own
        \coordinate (PPA-\name) at (\e,-1.0);
        \draw (\e,0) -- (\l,0);
        \draw (\e,0.1) -- (\e,-0.1) node[label=south: \footnotesize $e_{R_{\name}}$ ]{};
        \draw (\l,0.1) -- (\l,-0.1) node[label=south: \footnotesize $l_{R_{\name}}$ ]{};
    }


    \def\succr{14};
    \foreach \name/\x/\text in {4/15/14, 32/10/13, 31/7.5/13, 2/4.2/12, 1/1/11} 
    {
        \node[vertex] (V-\name) at (\x,0) {$R_{\text}$};
        \draw[dotted] (\x-0.3,0) -- (\x-0.3,-2);
        \def\nameref{\name}     

        \ifnum \pdfstrcmp{4}{\nameref}=0
        % do nothing
        \else
            \ifnum \pdfstrcmp{31}{\nameref}=0
            % do nothing
            \else
                \draw[->] (\x-0.3,-1.5) let \p1 = ($(PPA-\succr)-(PPE-\succr)$) in -- ++({veclen(\x1,\y1)},0) node{PPA-\succr};

            \fi
        \fi %

        \ifnum \pdfstrcmp{31}{\nameref}=0
        % ein königreich für != oder <> ... maybe \!= 
        \else
            \draw[->] (\x-0.3,-1) -- (PPE-\text);
            \def\succr{\text};
        \fi
    } 


    \foreach \from/\to/\fname/\tname in {1/2/1/2,2/31/2/3,32/4/3/4}
        \draw[->] (V-\from) to[out=30,in=150] node[above,sloped] {$d_{R_{1\fname}R_{1\tname}}$} (V-\to);

    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe this picture helps you to understand what i intent to do. The PPF line pairs should be of the same length. Every node draws its own PPF line. Then i try to save the name of the vertex as \succr. At the next iteration/node i calculate the length of the PFF-line at the previous node and \draw the corresponding line (of the \succr) at the bottom. 
At the moment the lines are not of the same length.

[image]

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is. To remember a variable in a `\foreach` loop use `\foreach \x [remember \x as \lastx] in{...`. You might also want to look at the `ifthenelse` package, although you can of course do and/or with nested if-statements.  Also you don’t need `\namref`: use `\ifnum\name=4...\fi`.

Comment: not really an answer but I'm wondering about your comment against the `\fi` isn't that the closing you expect for the `\ifnum`, the same as the one on the line above?

Comment: Why \fi instead of \endif. But it doesnt matter. A lot of things in latex do not even have closing tag.

Comment: there is a long tradition of programming  languages using inverted words as the ending: algol, pascal (the language tex was written in) bash all use if.. fi, case ... esac,

Comment: also your comment `\def` doesn't make reassignments is either mistaken or I do not understand what you mean. `\def\foo{a}.. \def\foo{b}...`  defines `\foo` to be `a` then redefines it to be `b`.

Comment: @user147582 You own the developers a kingdom, `\ifnum` is perfectly capable to test for `>` or `<`. For example `\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{42}

\ifnum\thefoo>0
 yes
\else
 no
\fi`

Comment: Ok thank you. Since i have to skip a node in the foreach [remember ...] dont do what i need. \def works at my name, dont know why the \succr isnt reassigned. I am not sure but i aspect \strcmp should return 0 if both strings are equal it and can also return values greater and lower than zero if the strings are not of the same length. So and simple >0 is not the perfect solution.

Comment: you really have not said what the code is intended to do.  isn't `\ifnum \pdfstrcmp{31}{\nameref}=0` just testing that `\name` is 31, which would be more natural to code as `\ifnum\name=31` ?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it works. But i am very uncertain because i cant see the type of the variables, so i want to be sure. Dont mind about my comment about the closing tag. I just dont like it. Sometimes we use a scope {} sometimes begin and end tags and in some other cases something else.

Comment: tex doesn't have types (or variables or tags) it just has lists of tokens.

Comment: Ok, i wont understand latex tonight. But whats the solution to my problem. You can see that i try to reassign \succr but obviously there is no reassignment.

Comment: sorry I do not know what your problem is, there is no actual question just some code and some derogatory remarks about latex syntax. perhaps you want to replace `\def\succr{\text};` by `\global\let\succr\text` but that's just a guess of your intended meaning here

Comment: Ok, thank you. Somethink changed but not what i want. The three lowest horizontal lines should have the same length like the second lowest line of the successor node. I'll start MS Visio and finish this in in couple of minutes

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!20,minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt}]
    \begin{scope}
    \foreach \e/\l/\name in {0/2/11, 3.5/5.5/12, 8.6/10.6/13, 14/16.5/14}
    {
        \coordinate (PPE-\name) at (\l,-1.0);
        \coordinate (PPA-\name) at (\e,-1.0);
        \draw (\e,0) -- (\l,0)
              (\e,0.1) -- (\e,-0.1) node[label=south: \footnotesize $e_{R_{\name}}$ ]{}
              (\l,0.1) -- (\l,-0.1) node[label=south: \footnotesize $l_{R_{\name}}$ ]{};
    }
    \foreach \name/\x/\text[remember=\text as \prevtext (initially 14)] in {4/15/14, 32/10/13, 31/7.5/13, 2/4.2/12, 1/1/11} 
    {
        \node[vertex] (V-\name) at (\x,0) {$R_{\text}$};
        \draw[dotted] (\x-0.3,0) -- (\x-0.3,-2);
        \ifnum\name=4\relax\else
            \ifnum\name=31\relax\else
                \draw[->] (\x-0.3,-1.5) let \p1 = ($(PPA-\prevtext)-(PPE-\prevtext)$) in -- ++({veclen(\x1,\y1)},0) node{PPA-\prevtext};
            \fi
        \fi
        \ifnum\name=31\relax\else\draw[->] (\x-0.3,-1) -- (PPE-\text);\fi
    } 
    \foreach \from/\to/\fname/\tname in {1/2/1/2,2/31/2/3,32/4/3/4}
        \draw[->] (V-\from) to[out=30,in=150] node[above,sloped] {$d_{R_{1\fname}R_{1\tname}}$} (V-\to);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a progress. But i want that the lowest three horizontal line have the same lenght like the second lowest line of the successor node.

Comment: @user147582 Then you can remove that computation and use a fixed length.

Comment: That was my first intend but i dont know how to calculate the length of a segment ... and i dont know how to \draw a line with a fixed length. Since i only need the difference of two x-coodinates all i found was this computation.
Because this is just a snippet of a bigger picture it would be hard to adjust every length by hand.

Comment: @user147582 Help me to understand. You are so embedded in your own problem I don't even know which segment or x-coordinates.